How to enable year selection in MUI DateRangePicker calendar?
MUI DatePicker shows a little arrow next to the year and month in the calendar. Clicking on it allows selecting a year. DateRangePicker, however, does not show that option in the calendar.
How to enable year selection for date ranges that include many years? Scrolling through months to go 10 years back is not very comfortable.
Thank you
